# Knockout.js click binding strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got some click binding, that must pass binding context value to the self function for further processing and this value has been passing successfully but function firing on page load instead of click.
So, here is ViewModel:

```
<script src="../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        function UserStatusViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.clients = ko.observableArray();
            $.getJSON("/api/users", self.clients);
            self.updatestatus = function () {
                $.getJSON("/api/users", function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.clients);
                });
            }
            //Here I'm getting correct data fom click binding context, but this happend on page load, not on click
            self.modal = function (un) {
                localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.setItem("speakto", un);
                window.location.replace("http://somehost/operator/dialog");
            }
        };
        $(function () {
            var vm = new UserStatusViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('users'));
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            chat.client.addChatMessage = function (name, message) {
                vm.updatestatus();
            };
            chat.client.updateStatus = function () {
                vm.updatestatus();
            }
            chat.server.userStatus = function () {
                vm.updatestatus();
            }
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And HTML markup:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: clients" id="users">
    <div class="dialogs">
        <div class="speech">
            <div class="online">
                <img alt="" data-bind="visible: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(IsOnline) == true" src="../img/online.png">
                <img alt="" data-bind="visible: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(IsOnline) == false" src="../img/offline.png">
            </div>
            <div class="ava">
                <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(AvaUrl) }">
            </div>
            <div class="name" data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(UserName), click: $root.modal(UserName)"></div>
            <%--<div class="dateok" data-bind="text: $data.Timer"></div>--%>
            <div class="text" data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(LastMessage)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Sorry guys, I did changed click binding syntax too fast, current is newest and the one I'm talking about.

Comment: I did changed to "somehost" as I don't want to show

Comment: What happened with the `bind` in your binding? This is the correct systax `$root.modal.bind($data, UserName)` like you had it before...

Comment: Sorry guys, that' was wrong version, reviewed one is here now.

Comment: This is wrong: `click: $root.modal(UserName)` because it executes the function when the binding is evaluated and not when the item is clicked. You need write `click: $root.modal.bind($data, UserName)` like had it before or `click: function() { $root.modal(UserName) }`

Comment: @nemesv, this $root.modal.bind($data, UserName) look like correct, but it's not working - it's sending observable instead of pure string.

Comment: Let me try both ways.

Comment: if your Username is observable then you need to write `click: $root.modal.bind($data, UserName())` or `click: function() { $root.modal(UserName()) } ` or change your `modal` function to `localStorage.setItem("speakto", ko.unwrap(un));`

Comment: @nemesv, could you please post this comment as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click binding `click: $root.modal(UserName)` is wrong because you are not passing in a `function` but the result of the function. So KO will execute your function once when it processes the binding and not when your element is clicked.

You need to use `bind` or wrap it into a new function if you want to [pass in additional arguments to a click handler:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters)

```
<div class="name" data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(UserName), 
                                   click: $root.modal.bind($data, UserName)"></div>
```

Or

```
<div class="name" data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(UserName), 
                            click: function() { $root.modal(UserName) }"></div>
```

Note: you don't need the ko.utils.unwrapObservable(UserName) in text binding just write `text: UserName`

However because your `UserName` is observable you need to handle it in your `modal` function:

```
self.modal = function (un) {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("speakto", ko.utils.unwrapObservable(un));
    window.location.replace("http://somehost/operator/dialog");
}
```

Or make sure that the click binding passes in the value with `click: $root.modal.bind($data, ko.utils.unwrapObservable(UserName))`

Note: since KO 2.3 there is shorthand for `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` and you can just write `ko.unwrap`

Comment: Yes, the best solution of yours is - handle passed observable in self.modal.

Answer (score 0):

let viewModel in JS is defined as:

```
viewModel = {
    clickHandler: function(model, e) { alert(JSON.stringify(model)); }
}
```

then you can bind it the following way in markup:

```
data-bind="click: clickHandler"
```

if you click it, the $data will be passed as "model" argument of the handler

It is described at the [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)